# how to Insert or update if already exists use Django and SQLITE

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to insert data in SQLite use Django, I want that if data is in Database exist, new record will only update my db, The next is if not exist will insert new.

```
class User(models.Model):
    email= models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    salary = IntegerField(null=True)
```

I tried to use

```
try:
     # update codes
except:
     # Insert codes
```

but failed, all times it insert and fail and it give me error of that email is unique, without update existing record.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use update_or_create.

A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs, creating a new one if necessary.

```
obj, created = User.objects.update_or_create(email='foo@bar.com', name='foo', salary=100)
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create